# "There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate" while installing python packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

The command `pip3 install package_name` is getting me an error saying certificate verification failed.

[Failed ssl certificate verification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdUoA.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a cert with this parameter:

```
pip --cert /etc/ssl/certs/FOO_Root_CA.pem install linkchecker
```

See: [Docs » Reference Guide » pip](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/pip/#cmdoption--cert)

Also check: [SSL Cert Verification](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification)